# Lifespan of Plutonians

Tags: planets, xenobiology, life, time-keeping

Honestly, I think my questions about a fictional Pluto are by far the interesting to me, so I have another question.

Now that I’ve got my humanoids pinned down, and what protects them from the cold, I would like to know.

How long should I make their lifespan?

At first I was thinking of making it 1,000 years, but then I realized that we arn’t using Earth time.

For context, although my Pluto is more Earth-like than the real deal, I would still like time to pass the same way there.

This means that a day on Pluto is equal to 6 Earth days, and a year is equal to 248 Earth years.

As for what Plutonians are actually like biologically, they are almost identical to Homo Sapiens, at least externally, but with a few differences. For starters, because Pluto has so little sunlight, their skin is deathly pale in appearence, making them appear almost as though they have albinism. Their eyes function very similarly to that of a cat, in that they function well in low light conditions.

While they can survive unexposed in lower temperatures than humans, they still need warmth to survive in Pluto’s harsh tempatures.

Knights do this by wearing a piece of clothing similar to that of a sock on their entire body, covering everything except for their eyes beneath their armor.

As for what they eat, because of Pluto’s frigid climate, plants are very rare. Because of this, the Plutonians have a primarily carnivorous diet.

Comment: Can you tell us more about Plutonians? You mention humanoids, but can you provide us with more details (like what protects them from the cold, etc.)?

Comment: I'm leaning toward VTC as opinion-based. Without knowing their biology or how advanced their society is, any guess for how long they should live can't be justified.

Comment: I’ll add more contex.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I'll have you know that all the rules I mention are based on Earth-based. When it comes to alien life, we ultimately have a sample-size of one. Despite our research on this matter, we ultimately have a series of really good guesses that determine an organism's life expectancy:

1. **[Hayflick limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayflick_limit)**: this limit determines the number of times a organism's cells can undergo cell-division. By just seeing this, we can assume that a being's body can only repair itself/grow so many times. That being said, it isn't a determining factor how long an organism will last.
2. **[VO2 Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_max)**: is the maximum rate of oxygen consumption measured during incremental exercise; that is, exercise of increasing intensity.

These are just two I have mentioned - you should check out [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_life_span) to learn more. Mean and maximum life-expectancies are also effected by the chance of fatally-risky situations being encountered by a species. But what I think really matters to your Plutonians is **how they use and conserve energy**. On Earth we can afford to take jogs and live a little because we live in a habitable zone for our type of organism. So, it could be possible that your Plutonians don't even need any kind of heat to keep themselves alive. So how do they get their energy? What do they feed on, and is it readily available?

I realize this isn't much of an answer, but I'm not working with too much information here. I think I'll edit this answer if I am given more info.